# Galois/Counter Mode (GCM/NoPadding) not used

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, aes-gcm

I have implemented `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` and want to move on to `AES/GCM/NoPadding` in Java 1.8 but keep getting an error of `javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!`

The current implementation of `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` is perfectly fine and in the recent SonarQube scans, I found out the `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` isn't secure and suggesting to move on to `AES/GCM/NoPadding`.

The encryption/decryption algorithm will be used in the REST API calls where the request body received will be encrypted, the application will be decrypting the body.

The REST APIs will be used by other applications and will have their own unique secret and salt values to encrypt and decrypt the data and at the backend, the application will be using the allotted secret and salt to decrypt or encrypt the data.

Below is the code of encryption and decryption I have written:

```java
public SecretKey generateSecretKey(String password, byte[] iv) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), iv, 65536, 128); // AES-128
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        byte[] key = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
        return new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    }

public String encryptWithGCM(String plaintext, String secret, String salt)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, ShortBufferException, InvalidKeySpecException {

        byte[] secretBytes = secret.getBytes();
        byte[] iv = salt.getBytes();
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        random.nextBytes(iv);

        SecretKey key = generateSecretKey(secret, iv);


        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, gcmParameterSpec);
        cipher.update(plaintext.getBytes());

        byte [] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes());

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 + iv.length + encryptedData.length);
        byteBuffer.putInt(iv.length);
        byteBuffer.put(iv);
        byteBuffer.put(encryptedData);

        return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(byteBuffer.array());
    }

public String decryptWithGCM(String encryptedText, String secret, String salt) throws BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException {

        byte[] encryptedData = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText.getBytes());
//      byte[] iv = salt.getBytes();        

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(encryptedData);
        int noonceSize = byteBuffer.getInt();

        //Make sure that the file was encrypted properly
        if(noonceSize < 12 || noonceSize >= 16) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Nonce size is incorrect. Make sure that the incoming data is an AES encrypted file.");
        }
        byte[] iv = new byte[noonceSize];
        byteBuffer.get(iv);

        SecretKey key = generateSecretKey(secret, iv);

        //get the rest of encrypted data
        byte[] cipherBytes = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
        byteBuffer.get(cipherBytes);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, gcmParameterSpec);

        byte[] decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText.getBytes());

        return new String(decryptedText);
    }
```

The encryption logic works perfectly fine and returns back an encrypted `String`, but when the returned String is sent for decryption application throws below error:

```java
javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:578)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1032)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:969)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:833)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at com.qfix.utils.VASDecryptService.decryptWithGCM(VASDecryptService.java:103)
    at com.qfix.controller.TestController.decrypt(TestController.java:47)
    at com.qfix.controller.TestController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ce1df123.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.qfix.controller.TestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92c88aec.decrypt(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried figuring out the issue and what I came to know that if the `SecretKey` is referenced from the same instance, both in encryption and decryption method then no errors are thrown, however, if the `SecretKey` is instantiated separately in encrypt and decrypt method (which is the requirement as both methods are in different classes and cannot be merged in one) then the above error is thrown.

If the above-mentioned case is correct then I believe, `AES/GCM/NoPadding` will work as the encrypted value will be received from the integrated application backend.

Also, if the above-mentioned case is correct, what would be the alternative to `AES/GCM/NoPadding` which is much secure than the `AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING`.

Comment: @kelalaka: what do you think is problematic? Using iv for salt is a bit dubious, and letting caller control length by using a discarded value is odd, but given those inputs and using Java that file format makes good sense to me. Your link is for dotnet not Java, and for CBC (with fixed size IV) not GCM (with somewhat variable IV), and thus not very helpful.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 nice catch. I've linked to a wrong article. In the protocol, the IV length is fixed, so there is no need to send the IV length.

Comment: There's also another small issue here, it should be if(noonceSize < 12 || noonceSize > 16) , since iv size can be exactly 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two minor bugs in the code that cause the observed `AEADBadTagException` (tag mismatch):

- In addition to the [`doFinal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal(byte%5B%5D))-call an [`update`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#update(byte%5B%5D))-call is performed in the `encryptWithGCM`-method. The `update`-call must either be removed or the result must be concatenated with the result of the `doFinal`-call (resulting in a *double* plaintext when decrypted). Otherwise, ciphertext and tag generally don't match (at least for a plaintext with a length of 16 bytes or more).
- In the `doFinal`-call of the `decryptWithGCM`-method `encryptedText.getBytes()` is used. This must be replaced by `cipherBytes`. The latter contains the ciphertext and the tag, while `encryptedText` *additionally* contains the information concerning the IV (and thus doesn't match the tag).

With these changes the code runs. Both bugs are independent of whether encryption and decryption are performed with the *same* instance or not, so (with regard to the last part in your question) there may be other (possibly environment-related) problems that I however can't reproduce.

Comment: @Topaco Your mentioned points, did help, it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: You're right: the _mode_ doesn't strictly require blocking, but both SunJCE and BC do so, and I didn't check as I should have. <Litella> Never mind. </>